# python -V vs python3 -V: Trying to get a basic/beginners understanding

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

I'm trying to learn some basics of Python integration on my Mac.

The crux of my question is: When I open my terminal and type python -V, it returns python 2.7.16.  If I then type python3 -V, it returns 3.9.7.

Assumptions:

1. I understand my Mac comes pre installed with Python 2
2. I recently completed a beginners python YouTube course in which I downloaded python 3 as well as PyCharm.
3. When I configure a new .py project in PyCharm, I select Python 3.9 as my interpreter.

I'm trying to bridge the mental gap and better understand the link between my terminal, PyCharm, and the different versions of Python.  If I downloaded Python 3, why isn't that displaying when I type python -V in my terminal, broadly speaking?

Comment: When you install a new python the alias `python` isn't update to the new python version

Comment: Also worth a read: https://askubuntu.com/questions/351318/changing-symlink-python-to-python3-causes-problems

Comment: Your terminal can be set up so that any command corresponds to any executable on your computer (either using `PATH` or through aliases). PyCharm can be configured to use any Python executable. You shouldn't read too much into what your terminal does by default. The important part is that `python3 -V` works and shows a Python 3 version and that whichever IDE you're using (e.g. PyCharm) is working with whichever Python version you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , Mac comes with `python2` preconfigured. And you are not seeing `python3`'s version by default due to reason that your `Path` is looking for system python first which is python2.
To appear `python3` in your path you need to add that in your path or you can set alias too.

The recommended way not to mess with path is create a `venv` that is virtual environment and start using that. It will avoid any mess of system settings and will point to desired python version